# Check if the following function is injective, surjective or neither (function in body)

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Is the function $\Bbb Z_{13} \times\Bbb Z_{13} \times \Bbb Z_{13} \rightarrow \Bbb Z_{13} \times\Bbb Z_{13} \times \Bbb Z_{13}\times \Bbb Z_{13}$ injective, surjective or neither? The function is: $(x,y,z) \rightarrow (x+2z, 2x+2y+z, x+4z, 3y+z)$

For checking the injectivity, I checked its kernel. By solving the linear system: $\begin{cases} x+2z=0 \\ 2x+2y+z=0 \\ x+4z=0 \\ 3y+z=0 \end{cases}$

I found that its kernel is trivial so the function is injective. Is that correct? How can I verify or exclude if the function is surjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about the injectivity proof.

Now, this function cannot be surjective, since the right side is "bigger" (it has dimension $4$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ while the domain has dimension $3$).

An easy way to prove it without using this fact is to give an element not in the image of your function. The values in first and third place completely determine the values of $x$ and $z$, so for example you can pick an element $(0,a,0,b)$ which can only be in the image of an element $(0,y,0)$. Now you have
\begin{cases} 0=0 \\ 2y=a \\ 0=0 \\ 3y=b \end{cases}

so just have to pick "wrong" values for $a, b$. For instance, if $a=4$ then $y=2$, so $3y=6$. If you pick $b=7$ then the element $(0,4,0,7)$ cannot be the image of an element in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}^3$ under your map.

Comment: A comment on your second paragraph, in case the OP hasn't studied vector spaces over arbitrary fields: you can show it's not surjective by counting the number of elements in the domain and codomain. The domain has order $13^3$, while the codomain has order $13^4$, so the function can't be surjective.

Comment: My proof doesn't really need to have studied vector spaces as well, I produced an element that cannot be in the image of the function!

Comment: Sorry, my comment was only in relation to your second paragraph.